# What is wrong with the way I have set up the Category .h file?

Tags: objective-c, ios9, categories

I have an iOS 9.0 app that I am trying to add In-App Purchase to; (I have never used IAP before and found some code online that will hopefully get me started).

I decided to make the code reside in a Category for maintenance simplicity (I have only used Categories once before).  That said, I'm having problems with the actual structure of the Category.  This is the .h file's code in the category:

```
#import "SettingsViewController.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface SettingsViewController (Purchases)

@end

#define kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification
@"kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification"

@interface InAppPurchaseManager : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate>  {

SKProduct *proUpgradeProduct;
SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
}

@end
```

This is the .m code:

```
#import "SettingsViewController+Purchases.h"

@implementation SettingsViewController (Purchases)

- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData {

NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"com.runmonster.runmonsterfree.upgradetopro" ];
productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
productsRequest.delegate = self;
[productsRequest start];

// we will release the request object in the delegate callback
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate methods

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response  {

NSArray *products = response.products;
proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [[products firstObject] retain] : nil;
if (proUpgradeProduct)
{
    NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
    NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
    NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
    NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
}

for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
{
    NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
}

// finally release the reqest we alloc/init’ed in requestProUpgradeProductData
[productsRequest release];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}

@end
```

The problem is the SKProduct and SKProductsRequest are not available to the .m file, which I'm sure is caused by the way I set up the .h file.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's the actual error and what is it?

Comment: Also, what's the point of using a category here? What does that get you?

Comment: Do you mean `proUpgradeProduct`? Yes, it looks undefined.

Comment: Hmm? There's something in the _.h_ file, but it's not part of the category's interface, so how would the category's implementation ever see it? It's unclear what you're trying to do with those properties, and it's unclear why the category header contains two different interfaces.

Comment: Those properties are supposed to be available to the .m file.  The issue is how to structure the .h file so this can happen.  It would work just fine if I didn't want to use categories, but it's not an option here.

Comment: "Those properties are supposed to be available to the .m file" How? The property is a property of some totally different class, called InAppPurchaseManager. I don't even get what that's doing in there. And anyway, you can't really declare a property in a category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use a category for an unsuitable purpose. In particular, it looks like your category is supposed to contain a property declaration. But, as [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) says:

> Categories can be used to declare either instance methods or class methods but are not usually suitable for declaring additional properties. It’s valid syntax to include a property declaration in a category interface, but it’s not possible to declare an additional instance variable in a category. This means the compiler won’t synthesize any instance variable, nor will it synthesize any property accessor methods. You can write your own accessor methods in the category implementation, but you won’t be able to keep track of a value for that property unless it’s already stored by the original class.

Comment: Thank you... I forgot about that, having only used categories once.  :-}

Comment: And in any case your "use case" for a category here didn't make any sense to me. :)

Comment: I think you're right... time to re-do it... thanks again... SD